# An elementary algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality

How do I go about proving that
$$\frac{x^2}{yz+2}+\frac{y^2}{xz+2}+\frac{z^2}{xy +2}\ge \frac{x+y+z}{3} $$
for $1\le x,y,z\le 2$ ?

This is straightforward when $x=y=z$, but I don't see where to go from there.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks a lot. How can I delete the question?